# How to use jquery ui tooltip in Drupal7?

Tags: 7, javascript, tooltips

I want to use jQuery UI tooltip in my Drupal7 website.

I have installed 'jquery-update' and 'jquery-plugins' module and added

```
$(function() {
   $("a").tooltip();
});
```

in js file of my template. But firebug gives this error to me:

```
$(...).tooltip is not a function
```

that show the website doesn't find tooltip js file.

Should I do something more to use tooltip jquery ?

Comment: Can you show us how you added the JS file in your template?

Answer (score 6):

Try adding:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.tooltip');
```

in your theme template.php file

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html
 */
THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables){
  drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.tooltip');
}
```

That should ensure the library is available. You can add various conditions to make it page specific as required.

Comment: This implies that the [jquery_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module shall be enabled